# Regulated function has countably many discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis

How do you prove that a regulated, real valued function defined on a closed domain has countably many discontinuities using the fact that it is the uniform limit of a sequence of step functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a regulated function and $(f_n)$ be a sequence of step functions converging uniformly to $f$. For any $n$, let $D_n$ be the set of discontinuities of $f_n$, and $D= \bigcup\limits_n D_n$.

Show that if $x \notin D$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$. Therefore, the set of discontinuities of $f$ is included in $D$, which is countable (since each $D_n$ is finite).